# MATCH smallest value equivalent code in python

Tags: python, pandas, match

I would like to seek the quickest equivalent Python code of the MATCH Excel function which returns the position of the smallest and nearest value of "VALUE" in a "RANGE", i.e. Match(VALUE, RANGE, -1). This function should be applied to multiple "VALUE", i.e, a vector.

I have an initial solution below but it is very very slow with a high number of element (100k):

In the example below I want to match each value in "vector" to find the position of its smallest nearest value in the "vector_to_match":

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot


simulLength = 100000

vector = np.random.rand(simulLength)
vector_to_match = np.arange(100000)/100000


def Match_Smallest(x):
    orderCheck = np.array((vector_to_match < x) * 1)
    x_order = sum(orderCheck) - 1
    return x_order

def A_Finding(x):
    return np.array(list(map(Match_Smallest, x)))


# what I want to get :
vector_position_outout = A_Finding(vector)

# but Match_Smallest(x) is really too slow
```

It takes about more than a minute for me to get the output vector A_Finding(vector). It would like to see if there is any quicker way to do it because Excel was beating me on my way in speed.

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n),  # or setup=np.random.rand
    kernels=[
        A_Finding
    ],
    labels=["c_"],
    n_range=[10 ** k for k in range(5)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
```

Comment: Have you tried with np.where(condition)? I'm not really sure if that is what you really want but it seems right.

Comment: Could you please elaborate an answer from my code above? Appreciate.

Comment: cannot understand what is the wanted output. provide an example please.

Comment: just edit my question. I want to replicate the Match(value, range, -1) Excel function in Python which return the position of the smallest nearest value of "value" in "range". But my code is too slow with high number of elements in "range" or in "value". If you just rerun my code by replacing 100000 by 10 you will certainly understand my question!

Comment: When `MATCH` is used to find the “nearest” it is leveraging sorted cells ... Use [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasting:

```
out = np.sum(np.array((vector_to_match < vector[:, None]) * 1), axis=1) - 1
```

Or like mentioned @donkopotamus in comments - use [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) :

```
out = vector_to_match.searchsorted(vector) - 1
```

Comment: @DiepN. - Ya, need memory, but should working better